# X-Frame-Options with intranet site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

I'm building a web application on Apache. To prevent "click-jacking", it's been suggested that:

> Most modern Web browsers support the X-Frame-Options HTTP header, ensure it's set on all web pages returned by your site (if you expect the page to be framed only by pages on your server (e.g. it's part of a FRAMESET) then you'll want to use SAMEORIGIN, otherwise if you never expect the page to be framed, you should use DENY).

However, I need to allow frames from one site. That's typically done (in .htaccess) like this:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://www.that-site.com
```

However (again), the site that I need to allow from is my local Sharepoint site (that we access via `http://sharepoint/SitePages/Home.aspx`). I tried a few different things, but they all bring down the site except `SAMEORIGIN`, which disallows the frames I need. There's a possibility that the settings are already in the php.ini, but I'm not granted access to that and I can't really bother my IT staff with such a problem this week.

Help?!

Answer (score 1):

For your information the ALLOW-FROM option is only supported by Mozilla browser.